# Find the two sequence same term

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ such
> $$\begin{cases}
> a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_{n}\\
> b_{n+2}=6b_{n+1}-b_{n}
> \end{cases}$$
> where $a_{1}=b_{1}=1,a_{2}=2,b_{2}=7$. Find the value
> $A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n},\cdots,\}\bigcap \{b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n},\cdots,\},$
>
> Find the set $A$.

My attempt:

Since the $\{a_{n}\}$ is $$a_{n}=A(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}+B(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}$$

Since $a_{1}=1,a_{2}=7$ then we have
$$\begin{cases}
A+B=1\\
A(2+\sqrt{3})+(2-\sqrt{3})B=2
\end{cases}$$ then we have $$A=\dfrac{1}{2},B=\dfrac{1}{2}$$
So
$$a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2}[(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}]$$
and  have
$$b_{n}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}(3+2\sqrt{2})^{n-1}+\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}(3-2\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$$
So we have find $m,n$ such
$$\dfrac{1}{2}[(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}]=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}(3+2\sqrt{2})^{m-1}+\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}(3-2\sqrt{2})^{m-1}$$

Comment: $A$ is nonempty $a_3=b_2.$

Comment: @BazyliZuczek, also $a_{1}=b_{1}$